# How to set data in checkboxCombo form?

Tags: extjs

I use ExtJS in my project and I can't set data in `Ext.ux.form.CheckboxCombo`. 
Has anyone been in contact with such a problem?

**CODE SNIPPET**

```
var checkboxCombo = new Ext.ux.form.CheckboxCombo({
    width: 560,
    mode: 'remote',
    name: 'cancelled_agreements',
    fieldLabel: 'Cancelled agreements',
    store: new Ext.data.JsonStore({
        proxy: new Ext.data.HttpProxy({
            url: '<?php echo $this->baseUrl(' / xxx / yyy / '); ?>',
            method: 'post'
        }),
        fields: [{
            name: 'agreement_id',
            mapping: 'agreement_id'
        }, {
            name: 'agreement_title',
            mapping: 'agreement_title'
        }],
        totalProperty: 'count',
        root: 'data',
        autoLoad: true,
        baseParams: {
            idsNotIn: 23
        }
    }),
    valueField: 'agreement_id',
    displayField: 'agreement_title',
    allowBlank: true,
    triggerAction: 'all',
    listeners: {
        beforequery: function(qe) {
            delete qe.combo.lastQuery;
        },
        'change': function(cmb, arr) {
            hiddenCheckboxCombo.setValue(checkboxCombo.getValue());
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Never heard about a "CheckboxCombo" component.

Comment: so is there any issue or error to set data ?